# Отсортировать положительные и отрицательные значения внутри переменной

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть переменная `df`.
Ее значения равны:

```
55
-316
148
-126
109
-168
41
-333
85
-123
70
-11
35
-97
190
-104
42
-136
144
-22
194
-64
23
-669
```

Как отсортировать по отдельности эту одну переменную в две разных, в одной - положительные значения, в другой отрицательные? Порядок чисел надо сохранить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
    col
0    55
1  -316
2   148
3  -126
4   109
5  -168
6    41
7  -333
8    85
9  -123
10   70
11  -11
12   35
13  -97
14  190
15 -104
16   42
17 -136
18  144
19  -22
20  194
21  -64
22   23
23 -669
```

положительные значения:

```
In [32]: df_pos = df[df['col'] > 0]
```

отрицательные значения:

```
In [33]: df_neg = df[df['col'] < 0]
```

Результат:

```
In [34]: df_pos
Out[34]:
    col
0    55
2   148
4   109
6    41
8    85
10   70
12   35
14  190
16   42
18  144
20  194
22   23

In [35]: df_neg
Out[35]:
    col
1  -316
3  -126
5  -168
7  -333
9  -123
11  -11
13  -97
15 -104
17 -136
19  -22
21  -64
23 -669
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно